# Why is the number if iterations in `fmincg()` random, even though the maximum number of iterations is fixed

Tags: machine-learning, vectorization, octave

I came across the function `fmincg()` which optimises the gradient update and runs the iterations and returns optimised parameters. Even though the number of iterations it goes through seems to be random. The `'MaxIter'` parameter is fixed to 200. Still the number of Iterations is random each time it is called.

Why is the number if iterations in `fmincg()` random, even though the maximum number of iterations is fixed?

```
costFunction = @(t) linearRegCostFunction(X, y, t, lambda);
options = optimset('MaxIter', 200, 'GradObj', 'on');
theta = fmincg(costFunction, initial_theta, options);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **maximum** number of iterations, not a fixed one. If the calculation converges before reaching the maximum number of iterations, it stops. If it doesn't converge, it will continue until it hits `'MaxIter'`.

Basically the program is a big `while` loop, which in pseudo code looks as

```
while iter<MaxIter & convergence_reached == false
    % Do calculations
    iter = iter + 1
    if converged
        convergence_reached == true
```

PS: this means that you input different values into your scheme every try, or that there's a random number generator somewhere in that code.